# Can the neighbours stop me from feeding the stray cat inside my home?

Tags: cats, feeding, strays

I stay in a rented apartment and I’ve been feeding a pregnant stray cat. She delivered the kittens 2 months back and she comes to me door in the morning and evening twice for food.I always feed the cat inside my house and leave her out after she is done eating. My neighbours are asking me to stop feeding the cat because they claim that the cat is tearing their garbage bags without having any proof. What do I do to stop this dispute

Comment: This seems like its more of a 'people' problem than a cat problem. Well unless the cat *is* tearing their garbage bags, in which case its both.

Comment: As a general rule you shouldn't feed feral cats at all. Your cat mom has just born 2 more stray cats and if she is well-fed, she will get pregnant again in a few weeks and give birth to even more stray cats... It's a vicious cycle, but by feeding feral cats you only increase the number of feral cats and the amount of suffering. I know it's hard and feels heartless, sorry.

Comment: If you're going to feed strays, seriously consider getting involved in a trap/spay/release program. But as far as tearing the bags goes: unless you can find a way to convince the neighbors that this cat is not the animal causing the problem (set up a video camera, perhaps) or you deny the cat access to the trash (bring her entirely indoors if she'll let you relocate the kittens?), you simply have to accept that your neighbors may be right and decide what, if anything, you are going to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the cat is doing this at all it is likely because the trash cans are a good place to hunt rats that are drawn to improperly stored trash. Having said that, cats aren't the only culprit. Raccoons or even dumpster divers could be rummaging through the trash, too. Find out if there is any security video in the trash pickup area. Regardless, talk to your apartment management about keeping trash covered. (Suggest you arm yourself with knowledge first. If you have questions about how trash ought to be handled in your community, contact your city's sanitation department or code enforcement office.) As to whether your neighbor can "force" you not to feed the cat, that is doubtful unless you are part of an HOA that specifically forbids it.